# Graqhql query works but can't use it because of multiimensional arrays

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have this file that I can't seem to get to work My development environment is currently gatsby, and I am having trouble integrating graqhql with gatsby. I know for sure that the graphql query is correct, because it outputs but because the there are two arrays, group[ edges []], I don't know how to call them. Any hehelp would be greatly appreciated, could anyone give me some advice. I am a relatively new programmer so all of this is confusing me a little.

in my tune-awesome.js page

````
    import {graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby'

    class BlogRoll extends React.Component {
      render() {
        const { data } = this.props
        const { group} = data.allSongsJson

        return (
            {group.map(({ edges }) =>
                   <p>{node.filesize}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
        )
      }
    }


    export default () => (
      <StaticQuery
        query={graphql`
          query byTuneAwemeQuery {
              allSongsJson {
                group(field: tune) {
                  edges {
                    node {
                      filesize                   }
                }
               }
              }
            }
        `}
        render={(data, count) => <BlogRoll data={data} count={count} />}
      />
    )```


    }
    ~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    ~
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do another loop:

```
groups.map(({ edges }) => {
  edges.map(({ node }, index) => {
    <p key={index}>{node.filesize}</p>
  })
})
```

You can simplify this nesting a bit by using `nodes` instead of `edges.node` in your query, and by aliasing for brevity/clarity:

```
query byTuneAwemeQuery {
  songData: allSongsJson {
    groups: group(field: tune) {
      nodes {
        filesize
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which you would then access more like this:

```
const { data: songData } = this.props

// first node filesize for each group:
songData.groups.map(group => group.nodes[0].filesize)
```

Comment: So I did the change, but it is giving me these errors,                                     
           /home/nate/neu-song/src/pages/accompaniments/sort-by-tune/index.js
  16:28  warning  Expected to return a value in arrow function                           array-callback-return
  17:31  warning  Expected to return a value in arrow function                           array-callback-return
  18:5   error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're just complaints from the linter. That said, it sounds like you might have an arrow function with curly brackets and no `return` statement?

Comment: Also, the query is a staticquery, not sure if that matters. So i implemented the mapping function change and fixed the errors by placing a return () statement, but nothing is displaying, got any ideas why that is, here is the code       {group.map(({ edges }, index) => {
  edges.map(({ node }, index) => {
    return (<p key={index}>{node.filesize}</p>)
  })        
})}

Comment: also, I am using these proptypes, ```BlogRoll.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.shape({
    allSongsJson: PropTypes.shape({
      group: PropTypes.array,
      edges: PropTypes.array,
    }),
  }),
}``` would that affect anything?